# How can I get the version of Rhino from within javascript?

Tags: javascript, rhino

Is there any way of getting the current version of Rhino within the javascript it is interpreting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This way:

```
var Context = org.mozilla.javascript.Context,
    currentContext = Context.getCurrentContext(),
    rhinoVersion = currentContext.getImplementationVersion();

print(rhinoVersion);
```

The output for the currently stable release:

```
Rhino 1.7 release 4 2012 06 18
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: What if the above returns null?